# Exception during loading file with extension "*.rtf" on ritchtextbox

Tags: c#

I wants to load a file(.rtf) on richtextbox using this code:

```
    OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
    OFD.DefaultExt = "*.rtf";
    OFD.Filter = "(*.rtf)|*.rtf;";
    if (OFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (OFD.FileName.Length > 0)
        {
            richTextBox1.LoadFile(OFD.FileName); // Exception occur hare.   
        }

    }
```

but i am facing an exception **File format is not valid**.
Name of file which i want to load is MyFile.rtf
This file contains simple text **Hello world** as content.
Why this exception is going to be raised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file needs to be in rich text format. Do you have MS Word? If you do type Hello world and save that as rtf then open the file in Notepad to see an example of rtf.

Answer (score 1):

The file represented by `OFD.FileName` needs to contain RTF text. From what you're saying it's just text.

If you look at [RichTextBox.LoadFile Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f99sst7(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll see the description for the exception you're getting:

> ArgumentException 
>   The file being loaded is not an RTF document.
>   <